# FindRoot on a 2D list of Equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a $n \times k$ Matrix of data that I want to feed into an equation and solve for an unknown variable. I suppose I can always just convert the Matrix into a long Array but I'd like to learn how to do this while keeping the data structure as is.

I want to be able to solve $n \times k$ `FindRoots` in one shot and mimicking some code from MMA.SE this is what I have managed.

```
f = x^(Mod[a, 3]) + b
a = {{2, 5, 8}, {1, 4, 7}};
b = {{-3, -5, -7}, {3, 5, 7}};
eqn = Table[(#[[j]] == 0), {j, 1, Dimensions[f][[2]]}] & /@ (f)
{{-3 + x^2 == 0, -5 + x^2 == 0, -7 + x^2 == 0}, {3 + x == 0, 5 + x == 0, 7 + x == 0}}
Table[FindRoot[#[[i]], {x, 1}] & /@ eqn, {i, 1, Dimensions[f][[2]]}]
{{{x -> 1.73205}, {x -> -3.}}, {{x -> 2.23607}, {x -> -5.}}, {{x -> 2.64575}, {x ->7.}}}
```

As you can see, this works but is a kind of a mess.  I am hoping I can be helped in the direction of a cleaner, better code and learn how to use pure functions on n-dimensional lists. Thanks.

Comment: What ? No xkcd?

Comment: The `f` should be after `a` and `b`, no?

Comment: @belisarius lol..

Comment: @J.M. It works either way.

Comment: @belisarius ... I wonder what's the over/under on a 100k views on this post.

Comment: @Amatya I can tell you that I posted my answer solely in the hopes of going viral. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
eq[a_, b_] := x^Mod[a, 3] + b == 0;
a = {{2, 5, 8}, {1, 4, 7}};
b = {{-3, -5, -7}, {3, 5, 7}};
eqArray = MapThread[eq, {a, b}, 2];
Map[FindRoot[#, {x, 1}] &, eqArray, {2}]

(* Out: {
  {{x -> 1.73205}, {x -> 2.23607}, {x -> 2.64575}}, 
  {{x -> -3.}, {x -> -5.}, {x -> -7.}}
} *)
```

Note specifically, that the `MapThread` command gets functionally right to the heart of the combination you desire.  Here's a 1D version.

```
Clear[a, b, f];
MapThread[h, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}]

(* Out: {h[a, d], h[b, e], h[c, f]} *)
```

Comment: The `== 0` in `eq[]` can of course be excised. :) You can then do something like `With[{a = {{2, 5, 8}, {1, 4, 7}}, b = {{-3, -5, -7}, {3, 5, 7}}}, Map[FindRoot[#, {x, 1}] &, x^Mod[a, 3] + b, {2}]]`

Comment: @J.M. You are one critical dude!!! :)

Comment: I still upvoted your answer, tho. :) I posted a comment as opposed to an answer since this is essentially equivalent.

Comment: @J.M. I know. I definitely appreciate your always insightful comments. Although, you could shorten your name.

Comment: Re: the addendum, if `h` is in fact a `Listable` function, then `h[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]` is equivalent to the `MapThread[]` construction.

Comment: Yes. While sometimes unavoidable, I tend to prefer direct functional programming, rather than the use of `Attributes`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure oh wow. `MapThread` does exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Amatya Awesome!